# Rendering a CSV sends a file (as if I used send_data) instead of rendering a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, mime-types, actionview

The following code returns me a `people.csv` file instead of rendering a text. If I am not using respond_to block and simply render a text, the browser works as expected. What forces the browser to send data in a file? The mime-type is 'text/csv', as expected.

```
# /app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { render text: "Hello, world" }
    end
  end
end
```

**Corollary**: rendering xls, which is a properly registered mime-type with a template forces rendering of application.html, which looks very strange to me.

```
# /app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls
    end
  end
end
```

.

```
# /app/views/people/index.xls.erb
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% @people.each do |person| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= person.id %></td>
    <td><%= person.name %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I noticed that this behaviour is not the same on all browsers. For example, it should work as expected on chrome.

Comment: I am working in Chrome and it still behaves the way I described.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the first part is to force text/plain mime-type with `content_type`, like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render text: "Hello, world", content_type: 'text/plain' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei, that solves the problem I was having after going back over [Railscast episode 362](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel). Does anyone know why this difference occurs? Assuming it's a change in the way render works between Rails 3.2 and rails 4.2?